# DNS speed for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Been testing the speed of access to my Google App Engine Golang project and looking as to why the DNS speed is so much slower.  Can't use the appspot.com address as can't protect against Man in the middle attacks as the SSL Certificate rotates.

I find with I call the App using the Appspot name the speed is acceptable, but when I use a customer domain name, the speed is substantially slower.

I've set up a ping function which returns the current server time and does nothing else.

```
func handlePing(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    timestr := time.Now()
    writer.Write([]byte(timestr.Format(time.RFC3339Nano)))
}
```

https://rapporrapp.appspot.com/ping gives ~290 ms from Australia to the US

https://app.rapporrapp.com/ping gives ~390 ms from Australia to the US

Have also done a test with Australian servers as Google App Engine is now available in Australia.

https:// au01rapporrapp.appspot.com/ping gives ~30 ms from Australia to Australia

https:// au01.rapporrapp.com/ping gives ~300 ms from Australia to Australia

Would like to know if this is expected behaviour for speed as latency is a major problem that I need to solve as when the number is lower, users feel your app is very "snappy".

Have also tried with Google Cloud DNS, and no improvement.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Google have a known issue in the Asia and Australia region regarding custom domains. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64458939 for more information.